# How to dynamically add a cell to UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to add a cell in `UICollectionCell` on run time. What is the best way that not affected performances?

And It's my sample cell class:

```
class PersonViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var coverImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel! 

    var p: Person!    

    func configureCell(p: Person) {
        self.titleLbl = p.title
        nameLbl.text = p.name
        coverImg.image = UIImage(named: "image-not-available")     
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include only the relevant code in your question, it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new instance variable in your class to store an array and save your JSON results to it. Then use that to return the number of cells in `numberOfItemsInSection`, and draw the cells in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. If you want to update after that, just call `collection.reloadData()`

Also, assuming you're making your network request on a background thread, make sure you call `collection.reloadData()` on the main.

Comment: correct, except the array does not have to be global (the code will be easier to mantain if it's an instance variable in the class which is `UICollectionViewDataSource`).

Comment: @Ollie U mean make var in ViewController class?

Comment: That's correct, in the same location as your `collection` variable